# SqlParameters in Repository unit of work pattern

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

In my Repository.cs, I have the below method

```
/*** Execute stored procedure ***/
public virtual void ExecuteProcedure(String procedureCommand, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
{
  Ctxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(procedureCommand, sqlParams);
}
```

Im calling it from my client repository as:

```
public bool CanLock(int spvId)
{
  SqlParameter[] parameter = { new SqlParameter ("spvId", spvId) };
  bool isLock = ExecuteProcedure("Exec prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock {0}", parameter);
  return false;
}
```

Im getting error:

> ExecuteProcedure has invalid arguments.

Can somebody suggest how to pass parameters.

Also, `prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock` has an output parameter, please also advise how can I pass output parameter and get the value to use in my client repository?

Comment: Anything to do with the {0} in your ExecuteProcedure("Exec prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock {0}", parameter) command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public bool CanLock(int spvId)
{
  SqlParameter[] parameter = { new SqlParameter ("spvId", spvId) };
  bool isLock = ExecuteProcedure("Exec prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock @spvId", parameter);
  return false;
}
```

You have to name the parameter in the sql command.

Comment: Sorry this doesnt not work, there is a problem with parameters type or something to do with params keyword

Comment: Maybe `new SqlParameter ("@spvId", spvId)`? And `params` allows you to directly pass the `SqlParameter`. No need to create an array beforehand (though it shouldn't cause an error if you do). Meaning you can do: `ExecuteProcedure("Exec prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock @spvId", new SqlParameter ("@spvId", spvId));`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using below:

```
    public bool CanLock(int spvId)
    {
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("spvId", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameter.Value = spvId;

        ExecuteProcedure("Exec prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock {0}", parameter);
        return false;
    }
```

Howerver is there any better way to handle this, like creating an array of parameters at one go ?